# docker build with nvidia runtime

Tags: docker, nvidia-docker

I have a GPU application that does unit-testing during the image building stage.
With Docker 19.03, one can specify nvidia runtime with `docker run --gpus all` but I also need access to the gpus for `docker build` because I do unit-testing. How can I achieve this goal?

For older version of docker that use nvidia-docker2 it was not possible to specifiy runtime during build stage, BUT you can set the default runtime to be nvidia, and docker build works fine that way. Can I do that in Docker 19.03 that doesn't need nvidia-docker anymore? If so, how?

Comment: Related to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70157364/docker-make-nvidia-gpus-visible-during-docker-build-process

Answer (score 71):

You need use [nvidia-container-runtime](https://github.com/nvidia/nvidia-container-runtime#docker-engine-setup) as explained in [docs](https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker/wiki/Advanced-topics#default-runtime): "It is also the only way to have GPU access during docker build".

Steps for Ubuntu:

1. Install nvidia-container-runtime:

   `sudo apt-get install nvidia-container-runtime`
2. Edit/create the /etc/docker/daemon.json with content:

```
{
    "runtimes": {
        "nvidia": {
            "path": "/usr/bin/nvidia-container-runtime",
            "runtimeArgs": []
         } 
    },
    "default-runtime": "nvidia" 
}
```

3. Restart docker daemon:

   `sudo systemctl restart docker`
4. Build your image (now GPU available during build):

   `docker build -t my_image_name:latest .`

Comment: This is due to a syntax error (extra comma in 6-th line). Fixed now.

Comment: FYI if you need this because you want to compile custom kernels with pytorch, you can use the nvidia development base image (e.g.  nvidia/cuda:11.0-cudnn8-devel-ubuntu18.04) and set `ENV TORCH_CUDA_ARCH_LIST=Turing
`, then you can also build them without having a GPU available during build

Comment: So, literally the *only* way to get `build` to use the nvidia runtime (or I guess, any other runtime) is to set it as the *default*? Geez. How is this not an option?

Comment: If you do this and are still having issues, make sure that docker-buildx-plugins is NOT installed

Comment: Following up on @Mason's comment, what's meant is `sudo apt remove docker-buildx-plugin`

Comment: Note that as of Oct 27 2023 nvidia-container-runtime has been deprecated. Instead, the recommended option is to use nvidia-container-toolkit: https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-container-toolkit

Answer (score 13):

**IMPORTANT NOTICE** 
(in addition to the [existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61737404/2496293))

Currently (march 2023), if you have docker compose installed, just configuring the default runtime may still not be enough.

In addition to configuring the default runtime, you have to disable the default docker build kit, with:

```
DOCKER_BUILDKIT=0 docker build <blah>
```

This applies even if you're not using docker compose, but it applies to docker compose as well of course.

See also:

- https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/9681
- https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/docker-build-starts-ignoring-default-runtime-setting-after-initially-working/111155/11

Comment: Thanks! you saved me! But WHY does this happen? isn't there any fix for this?

Comment: I think this is a regression between docker 23.x and docker 20.x.
https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/nvidia-driver-is-not-available-on-latest-docker/246265

Installing 5:20.10.24~3-0~ubuntu-focal resolves the error. As of this writing 5:23.0.4-1~ubuntu.20.04~focal seems to have the problem.

Instructions for installing a specific version of docker: https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/ in the "Install  Docker Engine". I did have to run a `sudo apt-get purge docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io docker-buildx-plugin docker-compose-plugin` to have everything removed properly.

Comment: This didn't help ... building it with DOCKER_BUILDKIT=0 or without it, during docker build the GPU is still not available.

(Docker engine version 23.0.5)

Comment: same issue with me. I am trying to build deepstream container for the PC but unable build. getting /usr/bin/ld: warning: libcuda.so.1, needed by /opt/nvidia/deepstream/deepstream-6.0/lib/libnvbufsurftransform.so, not found. If I run the image in bash, and build works as I have include --gpu all in the run. would be good to make it automatic than manual.

Comment: I was going crazy but this solved my issue. For the previous comments, you first need to set the runtime to nvidia (see the most upvoted answer in this thread) THEN build the container with buildkit disabled: `DOCKER_BUILDKIT=0 docker compose up -d --build`.

Answer (score 10):

A "solution" I found is to first run a base image with the host nvidia drivers mounted on it

```
docker run -it --rm --gpus ubuntu
```

And then build my app within the container manually and commit the resulting image.
This is not ideal and it would be best to have access to nvidia-smi during the build phase.

Comment: How would you create an image out of the result?

Comment: @Foobar you can create an image of a running container by using `docker commit CONTAINER_NAME TAG` from another terminal.

Comment: He seems to want to `build` the docker image not `run` it.

Answer (score 1):

I was to successfully run a custom-built `ffmpeg` in a `docker build` image. It was not easy to figure out.

1. Set nvidia to be the default docker runtime
   Make sure this line is in the top-level of your `/etc/docker/daemon.json` like @Anton Ganichev suggests above:

```json
"default-runtime": "nvidia"
```

2. Remove buildx as suggested by @Mason

```bash
sudo apt remove docker-buildx-plugin
```

3. Restart docker

```bash
sudo systemctl restart docker
```

4. Run docker build with stdin instead of Dockerfile. The reason is that otherwise, the binary sent to docker daemon will be extremely extremely large (like in the hundreds of GBs)

```bash
docker build - < Dockerfile
```

I have the following ENV variables in my Dockerfile:

```
ENV PATH /opt/conda/bin:/usr/local/bin:${PATH}
ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH /usr/local/cuda/lib64/stubs/:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/local/cuda-12.2/compat/:/usr/local/cuda-12.2/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/stubs:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
ENV NVIDIA_VISIBLE_DEVICES all
ENV NVIDIA_DRIVER_CAPABILITIES video,compute,utility
```