# Docker Run Has Access to GPU But Docker Build Doesn't

Tags: docker, pytorch, gpu, nvidia-docker

I'm building a DeepStream Docker image for NVIDIA GPUs as mentioned in this [link](https://docs.nvidia.com/metropolis/deepstream/6.1/dev-guide/text/DS_docker_containers.html#a-docker-container-for-dgpu).

I have the [NVIDIA Container Toolkit](https://docs.nvidia.com/datacenter/cloud-native/container-toolkit/install-guide.html) installed and The original Dockerfile works and after building it I can start a container with GPU support using this command:

```
sudo docker run --runtime=nvidia --gpus all --name Test -it deepstream:dgpu
```

The problem is that I want to install PyTorch during the `docker build` sequence and use it. As soon as PyTorch is imported in the build sequence, the `Found no NVIDIA driver on your system` error arises:

```
#0 0.895 Traceback (most recent call last):
#0 0.895   File "./X.py", line 15, in <module>
#0 0.895     dummy_input = torch.randn([1, 3, 224, 224], device='cuda')
#0 0.895   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/torch/cuda/__init__.py", line 229, in _lazy_init
#0 0.895     torch._C._cuda_init()
#0 0.895 RuntimeError: Found no NVIDIA driver on your system. Please check that you have an NVIDIA GPU and installed a driver from http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx
```

I have the proper driver for the docker:

```
NVIDIA-SMI 510.47.03    Driver Version: 510.47.03    CUDA Version: 11.6
```

And I can properly use PyTorch After `docker build` is done and I've started the container with GPU support.

So it seems that the `docker build` process does not take the NVIDIA driver or GPUs into account and I can only use the GPUs AFTER the build has been completed. It also seems that there is no `--runtime=nvidia --gpus all` flags to pass to the `docker build` command.

How can I fix this problem so that I can use PyTorch & CUDA during the build process?

**UPDATE:**
The problem seems to be because of the BuildKit version as discussed [here](https://github.com/moby/buildkit/issues/1800), [here](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/9681) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75629058/1417053). But I haven't still found the exact way to properly fix it (instead of setting `DOCKER_BUILDKIT=0`).