# How to make NVidia drivers available during docker build?

Tags: docker, gpu, nvidia, nvidia-docker

I am trying to build a docker image that has [dcn_v2](https://github.com/ifzhang/DCNv2/tree/pytorch_1.7) installed and built for CUDA support.

I have installed `nvidia-drivers` (450), `nvidia-cuda-runtime`, `nvidia-docker`, `nvidia-cuda-toolkit` on the machine.

my dockerfile starts `FROM pytorch/pytorch:1.7.0-cuda11.0-cudnn8-devel`

And at some point after installing other requirements has

```
 RUN git clone -b pytorch_1.7 https://github.com/ifzhang/DCNv2.git
 WORKDIR DCNv2
 RUN python3 setup.py build develop
```

I have followed the instructions found [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/datacenter/cloud-native/container-toolkit/user-guide.html) and made nvidia-runtime default for my docker, and restarted the system.

my `/etc/docker/daemon.json` looks like this

```
 {
 "runtimes": {
     "nvidia": {
         "path": "/usr/bin/nvidia-container-runtime",
         "runtimeArgs": []
         }
     },
     "default-runtime": "nvidia"
 }
```

I also tried following the suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59691207/docker-build-with-nvidia-runtime/61737404#61737404)

And build with `DOCKER_BUILDKIT=0 docker build <blah>`

However once i reach the installation I get an error

`RuntimeError: Found no NVIDIA driver on your system.`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I could not manage to make drivers available during the build. However if someone finds themselves in this situation:

1. Create a base image with just your "FROM" statement
2. Run your image with `--gpus all`
3. Build whatever you needed gpus and drivers for inside the container.
4. From a different terminal do `docker ps`
5. Get the id of the running container
6. Do `docker commit container_id Tag`
7. Use the newly created image as base and save that image somewhere

Looks super hacky, but hey - it works.