# error response from daemon: Unkown runtime specified nvidia after install nvidia-docker2

Tags: docker

After Installing nvidia-docker2

And run `nvidia-docker run --it deep3 /bin/bash`
then got the error **error response from daemon: Unknown runtime specified nvidia**.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [nvidia-docker : Unknown runtime specified nvidia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52865988/nvidia-docker-unknown-runtime-specified-nvidia)

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs seems when installing nvidia-docker2 it will change the /etc/dockerdaemon.json.

So you need to reload the daemon and docker as following:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl restart docker
```